# import .bcp file into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have downloaded some ZIP files from a government website for study  that are of type **SQL Server Replication Snapshot Bulk-copy Data File**. I am assuming they are **.bcp** files. I have also downloaded corresponding  **.sql** files to be created in sql server. There is an additional separate zip file that contains a large **.bcp** file with **no create table** .sql file so I am not sure what it is for.

They are saved in **c:\sadybcp\extract1...extract2....**
I have created a database called **test** with tables **extract1, extract2,** **extract3 etc** all tables being different. I  want to import them to my sql server. I searched unsuccessfully to get the syntax online , most of then are for **.txt** files. So I have tried various combinations but have failed.

For example I have tried 
 `Bcp Test.dbo.extract in C:\sadybcp\ extract.bcp`

but I get error  `unknown argumentextract1 on command line`

When I run `bcp "Test.dbo.extract1" in C:\sadybcp\extract.bcp -S SADYPC -T -E -n -b 10000`
I get error `Unable to open BCP host data-file`.

Please can anyone help me with the correct command ? I need to copy 15 files.

Comment: The second command appears correct. It just means that BCP can't get to the file. Note that that command line will import a _tab delimited_ file. You should open the file in notepad and confirm that it is a tab delimited file. If it's a binary file (just looks like a load of rubbish) then it's a different format

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is problem with path/filename in the first example you provided. You probably used copy/paste to fill path to bcp file (space in the middle, maybe some white signs).

The second error could occur when path/filename is incorrect, file doesn't exist or file is in use.

Is is worth noting, that paths are relative to where bcp utility is executing. Also be sure, that all security requirements are met (access to file).

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the pathname, so bcp thought it was another parameter. If you needed the space, you would put double quotes around the path.